# Group records by array value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array of arrays (CSV in array format), each row is a sale and then the inner arrays have the various details, however I need to group these into transactions to put through our till, with no 2 items being the same in each transaction, as our till do now allow for qty or manually adding more than 1 of the same item per transaction (shoot me!).

```
data=
[
    ['red apple', 'john'],
    ['green apple', 'jim'],
    ['red apple', 'terry'],
    ['green apple', 'baz'],
    ['small orange', 'dave'],
    ['red apple', 'tim'],
    ['green apple', 'sam'],
    ['red apple', 'steve'],
    ['rotten apple', 'me']
]
```

Needs to become

```
transactions=
[
    [
        ['red apple', 'john'],
        ['green apple', 'jim'],
        ['small orange', 'dave'],
        ['rotten apple', 'me']
    ],
    [
        ['red apple', 'terry'],
        ['green apple', 'baz']

    ],
    [
        ['red apple', 'tim'],
        ['green apple', 'sam']
    ],
    [
        ['red apple', 'steve']
    ]
]
```

What would the most efficient way be in Javascript/Jquery?

Comment: Can you describe the logic behind the resulting array a little better. It's hard to see how you come to that result. I can see that each group is effectively separated by the first duplicate, but in that case why does `rotten apple` go to the first group?

Comment: Basically each transaction can only contain one of any item, because thete is only 1 rotten apple it goes in the first transaction, because there are 4 red apples they have to be spread across 4 transactions.

Comment: Thanks all, I'll try these out when I'm home from work, much appreciated.

Comment: I benchmarked a 50k data set and the results were Me.Name 200ms, Asheesh 227ms, Neverever 381ms and Anticom 12724ms. Thanks all for the answers, I have +1 you all and will pick Me.Name as my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of a late addition, but I had a small trial left open in a back ground window and didn't want to leave it unfinished:

```
function GetTransitions(arr) {
    var ranks = {}; //object to hold count for each fruit
    var transactions = []; //result object
    arr.forEach(function(el){ 
      var transindex = (ranks[el[0]] || 0); //previous amount of fruit

      var transitems = transactions[transindex] || ( transactions[transindex] = []); //get existing transaction or start new one
      transitems.push(el);

      ranks[el[0]] = ++transindex; //store count for fruit
    });
  return transactions;
}
```

Example: [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/cuhidunafi/1/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 2):

Might not be the most efficient, but works: <del>http://jsfiddle.net/ej20ek1v/</del>

Basically you loop over the array, while it is not empty. Then you check if current key is already present in your `tmp` (representing a single transaction). If not present simply push it and remove it from the original collection. If is present you don't need to do anything. At the end of the for loop you add your transaction to your `partitioned` array. When your original data is empty you are done.

**edit 1**:
As @Regent pointed out, I had a bug in my fiddle. See fixed version: <del>http://jsfiddle.net/ej20ek1v/1/</del>

**edit 2**:
Still had a bug: While `data` not empty means checking for `while(data.length > 0) {...` not `while(data.length > 1) {...`

Sorry for the inconvenience. Final fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ej20ek1v/2/

Comment: Your result data structure is not the same to provided in question, is it?

Comment: @Regent OH, you're right. Sorry I didn't check the resulting array closeley enough. after `data.splice(i, 1);` you have to decrement `i` since an element is removed from the array. After this modification the code works: http://jsfiddle.net/ej20ek1v/1/

Comment: Sorry, did not have my morning coffee yet. Update two should be a working solution finally.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var data = [
  ['red apple', 'john'],
  ['green apple', 'jim'],
  ['red apple', 'terry'],
  ['green apple', 'baz'],
  ['small orange', 'dave'],
  ['red apple', 'tim'],
  ['green apple', 'sam'],
  ['red apple', 'steve'],
  ['rotten apple', 'me']
];

var map = {};
var max = 0;

for (var i in data) {
  var item = data[i][0];
  if (!map[item])
    map[item] = [];

  map[item].push(data[i][1]);
  if (map[item].length > max)
    max = map[item].length;
}

var result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
  var transaction = [];

  for (var item in map) {
    if (i < map[item].length) {
      transaction.push([item, map[item][i]]);
    }
  }

  result.push(transaction);
}

// print `result`
alert(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
```

Comment: I can't spot the difference. Could you point it out specifically?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data = [
  ['red apple', 'john'],
  ['green apple', 'jim'],
  ['red apple', 'terry'],
  ['green apple', 'baz'],
  ['small orange', 'dave'],
  ['red apple', 'tim'],
  ['green apple', 'sam'],
  ['red apple', 'steve'],
  ['rotten apple', 'me']
];
var transactionsClassifiedByApple = {};
var result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var transaction = data[i];
  if (transactionsClassifiedByApple[transaction[0]] === undefined) {
    transactionsClassifiedByApple[transaction[0]] = [];
  }
  transactionsClassifiedByApple[transaction[0]].push(transaction);
}

for (var prop in transactionsClassifiedByApple) {
  for (var i = 0; i < transactionsClassifiedByApple[prop].length; i++) {
    var currentTransaction = transactionsClassifiedByApple[prop][i];
    if (result.length <= i) {
      var tempArr = [];
      tempArr.push(currentTransaction);
      result.push(tempArr);
    } else {
      result[i].push(currentTransaction);
    }
  }
}
alert(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
```